# Worklight Single Step Adapter basede Authentication using DoJo

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.1 and DoJo 1.9

Using the Worklight sample for Single Step Adapter based authentication which uses jQuery, I was successfully able to implement this approach into my application.

I would like to implement the same approach using DoJo. I am new to worklight and DoJo development. I would like to have any sample code showing this implementation of Single Step Adapter based authentication using DoJo. I will appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is authentication implementation and it is done in plain JavaScript, not jQuery nor Dojo. It doesn't matter... Dojo controls the UI and stuff, not logic. It would be the same implementation.

Create your UI in Dojo. Use same logic as in the sample.